# Android Studio java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: module.B.package.R$string

Tags: android, dependencies, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio. I decided to test and import one of my applications for the Android Studio.

I've managed to import and configure Gradle, compiled just fine, the problem is, when I run the app, it gives me a NoClassDefFoundError error on the line where I get a string in an XML file.

The architecture of the project is more or less like this: Inside the project, the App which has as a module dependency A, which in turn has a B project as a dependency, which in turn has a dependency on the Maven project SherlockActionBar.

**App -> Module A -> Module B -> Sherlock (Maven)**

I did some tests and apparently works do this kind of structure without putting the module B as dependency of App.

The problem is when, inside the module B, I pull a string of one example.xml file. Someone help me please!

The error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: module.B.package.R$string
```

When I run the application in debug, I can see the R.class and the int value ID of the String.

I've tried everything, rebuild, clean, restart IDE, raining dance, magic, everything!!

**GRADLE APP:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.id"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':moduleA')
}
```

**GRADLE MODULE A:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "moduleA.id"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/estimote-sdk-preview.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile project(':moduleB')
}
```

**GRADLE MODULE B:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "moduleB.id"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/kilomobileds.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you're setting up the dependencies between App, Module A, and Module B in your build files, and how you're declaring the modules in your build files.

Comment: Does it work if you add an explicit dependency on module B in your main app?

Comment: No, I've tried this too. That's because the App have to call a method from Module A and this method call another method from Module B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory structure for Android studio & Eclipse are different. These kind of issues happen in AndroidStudio. I faced one such issue. Later, I added all folders as per AndroidStudio ( like inside src/main ) explicitly & it worked.

Comment: I fixed it!!

I created a new project and "copy and paste" the files module per module! Testing each one of them... Worked for me, but I think it must have a way to make this quick and simple!

Comment: Would you explain your solution with more details, pls.